# Main method that calls two method and passes result of calling first method over to second method

Tags: java, function, methods

I'm tasked to create a main method that calls two methods. The first method returns array of strings while the second method takes the array of strings and print out the element on separate lines. the main method then passes the result of calling the first method to the second and then halt. Am i doing it understanding the question correctly? When i compile and execute i get

```
sunshine
road
73
11
```

---

```
public class Hihihi
{

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
  method1();
  method2();//Will print the strings in the array that
            //was returned from the method1()
   System.exit(0); 
}                                 



public static String[] method1() 
{
     String[] xs = new String[] {"sunshine","road","73","11"};
     String[] test = new String[4];
     test[0]=xs[0];
     test[1]=xs[1];
     test[2]=xs[2];
     test[3]=xs[3];
     return test;
 }

   public static void  method2()
  { 
    String[] test = method1();
    for(String str : test)
        System.out.println(str); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, correct your `method2`

It has to be able to accept an array of `String` elements as parameter:

```
public static void  method2(String[] test)
  { 
    // this line is not needed -> String[] test = method1();
    for(String str : test)
        System.out.println(str); 
  }
```

This way, you actually pass the data to the method, as your requirements described. A bonus is: it's re-usable for other `String` arrays as well.

Your `method1` has got a lot of redundant code. Just filter that out

```
public static String[] method1() 
{
     return new String[] {"sunshine","road","73","11"};
}
```

and now, your `main` method, just to link them. Change

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
  method1();
  method2(); // this will now cause a compilation error, because it expects a parameter
   System.exit(0); 
}
```

to:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{      
  method2(method1());
   System.exit(0); 
}
```

The way your code was originally built, `method1` was called two times, first in the `main` method, which was completely redundant, since the result wasn't used, second time in the `method2`, where it shouldn't be called, since the data should be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, but in `main`, the return value of `method1` is ignored. And calling `method1` in `method2` is unecessary.

You can let `method2` accept parameter `String[] strings`:

```
public static void method2(String[] strings) {

    for (String str : strings)
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

and pass the result of `method1` to `method2`:

```
String[] result = method1();
method2(result);//Will print the strings in the array that
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want that the data "flows" trough main as  you should do this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
      String[] arr = method1();
      method2(arr);
      System.exit(0); 
}   

public static String[] method1(){
     String[] xs = new String[] {"sunshine","road","73","11"};
     String[] test = new String[4];
     test[0]=xs[0];
     test[1]=xs[1];
     test[2]=xs[2];
     test[3]=xs[3];
     return test;
}

public static void  method2(String[] arr){ 
    for(String str : arr){
        System.out.println(str); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Proper way of doing the above is like below.You have to take the return value of the method one and insert it into method two as a parameter.

```
 public class Hihihi
    {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      String[] test=method1();
      method2(test);
    }                                 



    public static String[] method1() 
    {
         String[] xs = new String[] {"sunshine","road","73","11"};
         String[] test = new String[4];
         test[0]=xs[0];
         test[1]=xs[1];
         test[2]=xs[2];
         test[3]=xs[3];
         return test;
     }

       public static void  method2(String[] newtest)
      { 

        for(String str : newtest)
            System.out.println(str); 
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there: the return of your `method1()` should be used in the first call (you are actually ignoring it), and you have to use that return value (I've made some notes in the code aswell):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String[] result = method1();  //TAKE THE VALUE HERE
  method2(result);//pass the result here as parameter
  System.exit(0); //there's no need of this, the program will exit when method2 is finished
}
```

So edit your `method2` for getting the result of `method1` as parameter

```
public static void  method2(String[] arrayToPrint){ 
    for(String str : arrayToPrint)
        System.out.println(str); 
}
```